# Why does the Django-Summernote prevents prepopulated_fields from working?

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg, summernote

I noticed Django-Summernote that I was willing to use in Django Admin prevents PostAdmin from working properly.
As soon as I try to replace the default content field with the Summernote one, Auto-Slug stops working and most of the posted contents' texts are not shown. I did a quick search and unfortunately, I could not figure out a way to solve this issue. Therefore, I would be glad if you guys tell me what's wrong.

This is my **admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status','created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}




class PostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('content',)


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: Why 2 different `PostAdmin` classes? Leave only first one, but inherit from `SummernoteModelAdmin` and define `summernote_fields` in it.

Comment: @OlegRusskin Thank you so much for the helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The SummernoteModelAdmin has the features of ModelAdmin so no need to create PostAdmin class twice. Simply replace admin.ModelAdmin with SummernoteModelAdmin in the PostAdmin class and add the summernote_fields variable to the existing variables like this:

```
class PostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status', 'created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    summernote_fields = ('content',)
```